# How to make a (private) class in java that is not visible to other classes in the same package?

Tags: java, oop, nested-class

I'm studying inheritance in Java and the book I'm studying from uses an `Employee` class to explain several concepts. Since there can be only one (public) class in a java file of the same name, and this class creates objects of another class, I have to define an Employee class in the same file, without the `public` modifier. I was under the impression that classes defined this way after another class body in the same java file **aren't visible to other classes in the same package**. Here's a sample Java code for demonstration:

```
package book3_OOP;

public class TestEquality3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Employeee emp1 = new Employeee("John", "Doe");
        Employeee emp2 = new Employeee("John", "Doe");

        if (emp1.equals(emp2))
                System.out.println("These employees are the same.");
        else
            System.out.println("Employees are different.");


    }

}

class Employeee {
    private String firstName, lastName;

    public Employeee(String firstName, String lastName) {

        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;

    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        //object must equal itself
        if (this == obj)
            return true;

        //no object equals null
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        //test that object is of same type as this
        if(this.getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;

        //cast obj to employee then compare the fields
        Employeee emp = (Employeee) obj;
        return (this.firstName.equals (emp.getFirstName())) && (this.lastName.equals(emp.getLastName()));

    }
}
```

For instance, the class `Employeee` is visible to all classes in the package `book3_OOP`. Which is the reason behind the extra 'e' in Employee. As of now I have about 6 employee classes in this package, such as Employee5, Employee6, and so on.

How do I ensure that the second class defined in this way in a .java file aren't exposed to other classes in the same package? Using other modifiers like `private` or `protected` throw errors.

Comment: Make Employee a private inner class.

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) for more information about *inner classes* (like PM 77-1 suggested).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make `Employee` a static **nested class** of `TestEquality3`:

```
public class TestEquality3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee emp = new Employee("John", "Doe");
    }

    private static class Employee {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;

        public Employee(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
    }
}
```

You should also do this to your other `Employee` classes. If there is any conflict with another class, you can use the enclosing class name to disambiguate:

```
TestEquality3.Employee emp = new TestEquality3.Employee("John", "Doe");
```

Comment: Oh I see. I'm not aware of this construct. How does `private` and `static` make the necessary difference in this case? I mean, you use `static` when you need to refer to a field/method without having to instantiate a class first. So, what's the theory behind adding `private` and `static` to the employee class here?

Comment: The difference is, that his class is *inside* another one. Your classes are not.

Comment: @Manish As Tom said, the main difference is that `Employee` now is a nested class of `TestEquality3`. I made it private so it can't be accessed from outside the enclosing class, but this is optional. Making it static means you don't need an instance of `TestEquality3` to use it. Check this [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260297/constructor-inside-inner-static-class-in-java/29260653#29260653) for more details.