# Java Generics - Need explanation for the signature of this Log4j2 class - RollingFileAppender.Builder

Tags: java, generics, log4j2

Can someone please explain me the meaning of the signature of this class -

`org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender`

`Class RollingFileAppender.Builder<B extends RollingFileAppender.Builder<B>>`

as documented - [Log4j2 apidocs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/RollingFileAppender.Builder.html)

I read it as `Builder` for type `B`, where `B` `extends` the *Builder for type B*, which confuses me like anything.

Also, this is a `static` class and it has a constructor as well. Is this normal? Can somebody please share a reference that can help me understand and use this in program?

PS -
About what I am doing here - I am working on modifying log4j code to make it compatible with log4j2, in which there is a `RollingFileAppender` created using `RollingFileAppender` constructor in a util class.

Comment: SO question [Contructor inside static inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260297/constructor-inside-inner-static-class-in-java) answers my second part around the constructor for this class.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588449/self-bounded-generics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Builders usually have a fluent API. I.e. their building methods return the builder class to be able to directly call other building methods. For example, the class in question - `RollingFileAppender.Builder` - can be used like this:

```
var appender = builder.withAppend(true).withLocking(true).build();
```

That means that the building methods (the ones that are prefixed with `with` in this case) must return the same builder instance. But ... If you design a builder class for being subclassed, you have a problem. What type shall the building method return?

Consider the following classes:

```
abstract class Builder {
    abstract Object build();
    Builder withProperty(String property) { return this; }
}
class ChildBuilder extends Builder {
    Object build() { return new Object(); }
    ChildBuilder withChildProperty(String childProperty) { return this; }
}
```

The actual return type of the `build` method does not matter for this explanation. The problem now is ... you can't do the following:

```
var obj = new ChildBuilder()
    .withProperty("property")
    .withChildProperty("child property") // Compiler error here!
    .build();
```

The return type of `withProperty` is `Builder`, and this type does not know about the building method `withChildProperty`. So you are breaking the fluent API.

The solution: A parameterized builder class. The type parameter `B` in the following example is intended to express the concept of a *self type*.

For our example, you do the following:

```
abstract class Builder<B extends Builder<B>> {
    abstract Object build();
    B withProperty(String property) { return this; } // Note the return type here.
}
final class ChildBuilder extends Builder<ChildBuilder> {
    Object build() { return new Object(); }
    ChildBuilder withChildProperty(String childProperty) { return this; }
}
```

Now you can do the code as I mentioned above.

Comment: A good explanation that buries the lede: "B is intended to be 'self-type'". Without that context it's a little hard to follow the otherwise excellent explanation as to _why_ a 'self type' is needed for subclassable builders.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2165660/5133585).

As far as I know, `RollingFileAppender.Builder` doesn't have any subclasses, so this isn't technically needed for `RollingFileAppender.Builder` to work. It could have been declared as a non-generic type:

```
public static class RollingFileAppender.Builder extends 
    AbstractOutputStreamAppender.Builder<RollingFileAppender.Builder>
```

and its builder methods, which all return a `B` (e.g. `withAdvertise`), can just as well return `RollingFileAppender.Builder`.

However, consider the case where someone is trying to write a subclass of this non-generic class:

```
public class FooBuilder extends RollingFileAppender.Builder {
    public FooBuilder withFoo(String foo) {
        // ...
        return this;
    }
}

// Let's try using MyBuilder:
new FooBuilder()
    .withAdvertise(false) // let's call one of the methods in RollingFileAppender.Builder first...
    .withFoo("Foo") // and now we try to call my subclass's method
    .build()
```

The call `withFoo` would not compile. This is because in our hypothetical, non-generic `RollingFileAppender.Builder`, `withAdvertise` returns `RollingFileAppender.Builder`, not `MyBuilder`.

Making `RollingFileAppender.Builder` generic, and making its builder methods return the generic type parameter `B` solves this problem. Because then we could write:

```
// in this pattern,
// you are always expected to put the class that you are declaring as B
public class MyBuilder extends RollingFileAppender.Builder<MyBuilder>
```

Whatever methods declared in `RollingFileAppender.Builder` that returns a `B` will now return a `MyBuilder`.

```
new MyBuilder()
    .withAdvertise(false) // this now returns a MyBuilder
    .withFoo("Foo") // and this now works
    .build()
```

It would also be helpful to see the inheritance hierarchy of `RollingFileAppender.Builder`:

```
java.lang.Object
    org.apache.logging.log4j.core.filter.AbstractFilterable.Builder<B>
        org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractAppender.Builder<B>
            org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.Builder<B>
                org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.Builder<B>
```

As you can see, this class inherits a lot of builder methods. If none of the classes followed this curiously recurring template pattern, you would not be able to call methods declared in `RollingFileAppender.Builder` after using one of the methods inherited from its superclasses.

```
new RollingFileAppender.Builder()
    .setImmediateFlush(true) // this is declared in AbstractOutputStreamAppender.Builder
    // so the above would have returned an AbstractOutputStreamAppender.Builder
    .withAdvertise(true); // now you wouldn't be able to do this
```

To summarise, this `B` is simply a way for all the builder methods to return whatever `Builder` subclass that you are using, rather than the class that declared them. Although it is not needed for `RollingFileAppender.Builder` since it has no subclasses, the authors still declared it like that, presumably to follow the pattern.

---

As for why `static` classes can have constructors, `static` classes just means that you don't need an instance of the outer class (`RollingFileAppender`) in order to instantiate the nested class. It does not prevent declaring constructors.